# Sequence with arbitrarly small p-norm but constant 1-norm

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to answer this question:

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $\epsilon>0$. Is there a sequence $\delta=\{\delta_n\}$ of positive numbers such that $||\delta||_1=1$ and $||\delta||_p<\epsilon$?

Thanks to anyone who has some ideas.

Comment: What is $\delta_n$? What are **your** thoughts on it?

Comment: It's just a a positive number. The problem has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $k \in \Bbb{N}_{\ge 1}$ consider the sequence

$$s_k(n) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2k} & \mbox{if } n \in \{ 1, \dots , k\} \\ 2^{-n-k+1} & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

For all $k$ you have $||s_k||_1=1$, but $$\lim_{k \to \infty} ||s_k||_p = 0$$